# Building driver for a Mygica USB tv tuner

Tags: driver, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, television-tuner

I'm trying to build a driver on my Raspberry Pi zero 2W for a Mygica USB tv tuner obtained from Aliexpress (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1883597971.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.11.1e6f1802V06dze).

I have used followed this link to do the build [www.mygica.com/support](http://www.mygica.com/support), and the device is model number T230A.

Embedded within the raspberry pi driver download is this guide to building the driver: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mgphbZjBeR3ZFV6Y6hA6b6mrI1gBFpOl/view?usp=share_link

And this extract is the first steps in the guide:

Building the Kernel

Install Required Dependencies and Toolchain

sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev make libc6-dev
libncurses5-dev

Install the 32-bit Toolchain for a 32-bit Kernel

sudo apt install crossbuild-essential-armhf

Build sources

For Raspberry Pi 2, 3, 3+ and Zero 2 W, and Raspberry Pi Compute Modules 3 and 3+:

cd linux

KERNEL=kernel7

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bcm2709_defconfig

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs

I've tried these scripts on two systems.
On my Raspberry Pi 4B running:
Description: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release: 11
Codename: bullseye

And also on my Windows 11 system using VirtualBox to run  this Linux system:
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

On both systems the two sudo apt install.... steps work fine. But then the instruction is to cd linux. And no such folder exists, as far as I have searched. So I am confused as to what I am doing wrong, and hope somebody with greater knowledge may be able to steer me in the right direction, with a plea  of "please nicely" :).

Kind regards to all who read this,
Peter

Comment: Why did you not get the Pi TV Hat? https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-tv-hat/

Comment: I wanted a more flexible solution that would work across platforms, ie Linux, Android and Windows, and this seemed to provide such at a far lower cost to a branded product like Hauppauge. But it looks like my choice was not optimal!!

Comment: Agreed with you.

Comment: I've sorted this now. A Raspberry Pi forum topic here; https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2104894#p2104894 indicates that this step was missing: git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux. having included this, all came good.